# android asus tf300 - external waas gps

Tags: android, gps

I want to get an external waas gps for use with my new asus transformer tf300. The built in GPS (assisted GPS) is not accurate enough for some marine based applications I am writing.

The tf300 has no usb slot - just an hdmi out and bluetooth - of course Im looking at the bluetooth option.

Has anyone used an external bluetooth waas gps with the android? Im assuming that this will show up in my list of location providers in the devices settings when the external gps is within bluetooth range. Im also assuming that that will be listed as an option within my application when I call LocationManager.getProvider().

Anyone had any luck with external GPSs?

Also based on my research WAAS gps is what I should be using for best accuracy. The device will be for marine applications requiring less than 10 feet of accuracy. Is there any different gps technology I should be looking at instead?

Comment: Given you are asking 2 different questions, I would suggest you split this up into 2 questions and ask both on a different SE site as neither is really on topic for SO.  I would try to ask about the external BT on [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/).  It is not geared towards programming, but you should get some feedback from users.  As for GPS technolgoy, check out [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks for the response. Ill check out the other site for the non programming question.